# Vector/Matrix of NaNs in armadillo?

Tags: c++, armadillo

What's the best way to initialise a vector as NaN is Armadillo?

My current solution:

```
vec v = zeros(n) * datum::nan;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is:

```
vec v(n);
v.fill(datum::nan);
```